# Should questions about building codes and electrical codes be considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, scope

Should questions about building codes and electrical codes be considered on-topic?  StackExchange sites usually shy away from narrowly localized questions, but building and electrical codes have many commonalities within the United States.  And knowing the answer even for a different locality than your own is informative: at the very least, it helps you find the terms to search for in your local code.

Answer (score 5):

I think they should be on-topic but have to be tagged with the location.  Otherwise people will not know that they have to keep to codes.

Comment: I think _answers_ should specify location.  The _question_ can be more general and collect answers for different localities.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be erring on the side of caution and saying "Off Topic" - as you said, they're SO localised.

And I don't mean any offense to anyone, but the fact of the matter is that a lot of people forget that there's a big wide world out there and that their codes may not be the same as someone elses.

For example, I saw a question regarding rewiring electrical sockets, and the colours they used for the wiring are different to the colours we use in Australia, which may cause problems if I were an Australian coming on here and seeing "Oh, look, brown = neutral" when in fact brown = active.

Comment: Brown = neutral?? Best not come to Europe, then!

Answer (score -1):

At the very least these must be tagged.

Power is especially tricky, not least as in some places it's illegal to do unlicensed electrical work.

The site should definitely have a large disclaimer somewhere disavowing responsibility for breakage, damage, injury or death...