# Should we update our electrical tags?

Tags: discussion

Currently there is a [220v](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/220v) tag, which seems to be used for both US 240V and UK 230V. I propose we create two separate tags [240v](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/240v) and [230v](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/230v), and eliminate the [220v](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/220v) tag.

110 and 220 are terms more commonly used by amateurs, where as 120/240V, 240V, and 230V are the accepted industry standards.

*Side note: I've already created a [120-240v](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/120-240v) tag, to represent 120/240V single split phase systems.*

Comment: Would 220V then become a synonym for either of these? Since I'm not at all an electrician, if I were asking about electrical, I'd use non-standard terminology (or at least, what *I thought* was correct, anyway) to describe my issue.

Comment: @Aarthi I'm not sure.

Comment: I looked through all the questions tagged [tag:220v] and they all looked North American to me (based on the OP's explicitly stating where they are in the question, user profiles, or other clues like talking about 12-2 wire).  Which ones did you think were UK-specific?

Answer (score 1):

Why not add the locale? `eu-230v`, `na-120v` (or `north-america-120v`). Trying to map the convention of 220 vs 230 vs 240 and get people to understand it enough to also understand the locale seems like a futile effort.

Maybe we even just drop the voltage entirely: `electrical-north-america`, `electrical-eu`, `electrical-japan`.

For the purposes of this site, 120 vs 240 is pretty much irrelevant. If it's also tagged with `dryer` or `stove` then it's implied 240v, and I think that will better lead people to finding similar questions anyway.

Comment: Related: http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/691/should-the-electrical-tag-be-removed-and-replaced-with-electrical-region

Comment: The point of this change isn't to help distinguish between locations, it's simply to be more technically correct.  While *we* cannot control the terminology the users use in questions and answers, *we* can control the tags they use. It makes the site look more credible if it's using proper terminology.  With all that said, maybe you're right about simply dropping the 220v tag and simply not replacing it.

Comment: @Tester101 [I gave an answer](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/794/157) to the question NiallC referred me to that states my views on this. If that's where we're going, we can probably close these tickets as duplicates. Right now it seems like there's a lot of overlap because they came into this from different directions but I believe that they can both be focused to the same issue. In other words, if this answer is acceptable than this question is a dupe of http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/questions/691/should-the-electrical-tag-be-removed-and-replaced-with-electrical-region.

Comment: Again. This change has nothing to do with region, it's only to increase credibility.